# ReportExecution2005.ReportExecutionService.Render() returns with no data after about 2 minutes

Tags: timeout, reportingservices-2005

I have a c# web app that takes a request from the user and exports data in SQL Server to Excel via RS2005. The code looks like this:

```
ReportExecution2005.ReportExecutionService rsExec = new ReportExecution2005.ReportExecutionService();

// set all params here...

rsExec.Timeout = 1800000;  //30 mins

s.Start(); // stopwatch start
result = rsExec.Render(format, null, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);
s.Stop();// stopwatch stop
```

The problem is that when the request takes more than 2 minutes (to simulate I have a "waitfor delay '00:04:00'" in my stored proc) the .Render() method returns after 2 minutes with no data. There is valid data for the params I'm passing in, because when I remove the delay in the stored proc the data is returned. But when I add the delay the Render() method returns with no data. I expect to get the whole data after the stored proc delay.

I don't think this is related to Reporting Services, since the same report works fine when we create a subscription with the same data the report runs as long as it needs to and data is returned. It's not throwing a timeout exception. It just stops working usually around 2 mins 4 secs, and no data is returned. Anybody have any idea on this?

Thanks in advance.

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem. Turns out that RS.Render() was calling a web service that itself had several timeouts associated with it. It was returning because a timeout was thrown from the service call, but it doesn't know how to pass the exception along, so no data was returned, and no exception.

Comment: Hi Ben, what is the timeout setting for render method ?. I have similar issue and cant see any other timeout on ReportExecution2005 class

Comment: @Zeus I've since moved from that project, but if I remember correctly I had to log onto the Reporting Services server and set it there. This link may help you: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj969577.aspx

Comment: Look at the section titled "Specify the report execution time-out period for all reports"